# Anomalous probability result for computed single pair probability when dealing seven card poker hands

Tags: python, simulation, probability, poker

**BACKGROUND:**  Today I thought I'd begin a small project building a poker
simulator.  The first task I set was to deal cards from a shuffled
deck, and check the various numerically generated probabilities
against accepted values.  The first such probability I checked was
the single pair probability--that is, generating (numerically) the
probability of being dealt a single pair, given as inputs the number
of cards dealt and the number of hands dealt, where each hand
is dealt from a separate shuffled deck.  Cards are dealt from the
top of the deck.  Below I show the beginning of that program.
I first tested numerically generated single pair probability
for five card hands.  The computed value comes to within
a tenth of a percent of the accepted single pair probability
for five card hands (but always high by about a tenth of a percent):  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability

However, when I test the numerically generated single pair probability
for seven card hands, I find that I am off by 4% to 5% from the
accepted value (e.g., typical computed value = 0.47828; accepted value as per above = 0.438).  I've run the numerical experiments up to ten
million hands dealt.  The computed single pair probability for seven
card hands is stable, and remains off by 4% to 5% from the accepted value.  It's not clear
why this is the case.

**QUESTION:**  Why is this the case?  I suspect that my code is not taking
something into account, but I cannot detect what.  Python code follows . . .

**NOTE:**  Issue 31381901 is similar to this one.  But in the below code the issue of double counting is accounted for by converting the dealt hand to a set, which will eliminate duplicate values, thus reducing the size of the set (in the case of 7 card hands) from 7 to 6.  That reduction indicates a single pair.  If three-of-a-kind is present, then the size of the set would be 5, since two of the three cards in the three-of-a-kind would be eliminated by the set conversion.

```
from random import shuffle

def make_deck():
    '''Make a 52 card deck of cards.  First symbol
    is the value, second symbol is the suit.  Concatenate
    both symbols together.
    Input:  None
    Output:  List
    '''
    value = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
    suit = ['C','H','S','D']
    deck = [j+i for j in value for i in suit]
    return deck


def shuffle_deck(deck, times_to_shuffle=7):
    '''Shuffle a deck of cards produced by make_deck().
    Default:  7 times.
    Input:  list, int
    Output:  list (modified in-place)
    '''
    for n in range(times_to_shuffle):
        shuffle(deck)


def test_for_single_pair(hand, cards_per_hand):
    '''Tests for presence of a single pair in 
    a dealt hand by converting the hand to a set.
    The set representation of a hand with a single
    pair will have one less member than the original
    hand.
    Input: list, int
    Output:  int
    '''
    hand_values_lst = [card[0] for card in hand]
    hand_values_set = set(hand_values_lst)
    set_size = len(hand_values_set)

    if set_size == (cards_per_hand - 1):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def deal_series_of_hands(num_hands,cards_per_hand):
    '''Deals a series of hands of cards and tests
    for single pairs in each hand.  Creates a deck
    of 52 cards, then begins dealing loop.  Shuffles
    deck thoroughly after each hand is dealt.
    Captures a list of the dealt hands that conform
    to the spec (i.e., that contain one pair each),
    for later debugging purposes
    Input:  int, int
    Output:  int, int, list
    '''

    deck = make_deck()
    single_pair_count = 0
    hand_capture = []

    for m in range(num_hands):
        shuffle_deck(deck)
        hand = deck[0:cards_per_hand]    #first cards dealt from the deck
        pair_count = test_for_single_pair(hand, cards_per_hand)
        if pair_count == 1:
            single_pair_count += pair_count
            hand_capture.append(hand)

    return (single_pair_count, num_hands, hand_capture)



cards_per_hand = 7   #User input parameter
num_hands = 50000    #user input parameter

single_pair_count, num_hands_dealt, hand_capture = deal_series_of_hands(num_hands, cards_per_hand)
single_pair_probability = single_pair_count/ num_hands_dealt
single_pair_str = 'Single pair probability (%d card deal; poker hands): '%(cards_per_hand)
print(single_pair_str, single_pair_probability)
```

Comment: Your code counts five hearts plus a pair of tens as a pair, but the linked article counts that as a flush.

Comment: where is `count` defined in `single_pair_probability = count / num_hands_dealt`

Comment: @briancaffey:  Sorry.  That got lost in the copy and paste.  I'll edit it now.  It should be single_pair_count.  Just reran with same result.

Comment: @John Gordon:  Aha!  Yes, that's it.  Many thanks!

Comment: Shuffling more than once is superfluous. If the algorithm is correct, doing it seven times is just a waste. If it's incorrect, doing it wrong seven times won't help. Python does it right.

Comment: Also, `''.join(i+j)` is just a slower way to say `i+j`.

Comment: @Lee:  Yes, of course!  What was I thinking!  :)  Made the edit.  Thanks!

Comment: @Lee:  w/r/t shuffling:  In other work that I do, I rely on the 1992 Bayer Diaconis result (http://statwugeb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/bayer92.pdf), which indicates (roughly) that 7 riffle shuffles is sufficient to destroy sequence patterns.  The random.shuffle function is not a riffle shuffle, of course, but the Diaconis result can be viewed as an upper bound.  Some follow-up empirical testing, using the (again rough) metric of size of zipped file as a measure of "randomness content" verified that 1 shuffle is sufficient.  Again, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Exactly, Diaconis's result applies only to human-like riffles, not to shuffles that are already statistically perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the hand contains a single pair but also contains a higher-value unit such as a straight or a flush, your code still counts that as a pair, where the probability article does not.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you're writing a simple, straightforward poker hand evaluator (that is, one not using fancy algorithms and lookup tables like the fast ones), it's better to test for hand values from the top down: That is, test for straight flush, quads, full house, etc., down to one pair, in that order.

Comment: @Lee:  I agree, for a simple, straightforward poker hand evaluator.  That's not my ultimate goal here, but instead emerged as an intermediate step along the way.  I decided to build a simple evaluator for study purposes to reach the other end point. Clearly, evaluating from the top down, i.e., straight flush followed by four of a kind, etc. will eliminate the higher value hands first, which is the correct way to go when evaluating poker hands.  Again, much appreciate your insights!